# how to update or replace dataframe value using the value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the dataframe cell(?) value as shown below

| before | col1 |  | after | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10.0 | - | 0 | 10.0 |
| 1 | 20 (15) | - | 1 | 20.0 |
| 2 | ND | - | 2 | None |
| 3 | 30.0 | - | 3 | 30.0 |
| 4 | 40.0 | - | 4 | 40.0 |

```
df=pd.DataFrame([10.0, '20 (15)', 'ND', 30.0, 40.0], columns=['col1'])

for data in df['col1']:
    if type(data) is str:
        temp=data.split(' ')[0]
        if data == 'ND':
            data = None
        else:
            data = float(temp)
```

this code don't update the dataframe value.

help please

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas alternative [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)[`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) first, if integers get missing values so replace values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and convert to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if non numbers:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].str.split().str[0]
                                     .fillna(df['col1']), errors='coerce')
print (df)
   col1
0  10.0
1  20.0
2   NaN
3  30.0
4  40.0
```

If need extract first integer or floats use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['*10.0', '20 (15)', 'ND', 30.0, 40.0], columns=['col1'])

df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False)
                                     .fillna(df['col1']), errors='coerce')
print (df)
   col1
0  10.0
1  20.0
2   NaN
3  30.0
4  40.0
```

Comment: thanks your code works but not working for df=pd.DataFrame(['*10.0', '20 (15)', 'ND', 30.0, 40.0], columns=['col1'])

Comment: @Yalgee - second solution is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify your data in a loop. In you case, while you modify the variable `data`, this one is no longer linked to the DataFrame's data. In addition, while there are methods to do this, looping over rows is inefficient.

You can use vectorial code instead:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].astype(str).str.extract('([.\d]+)', 
                           expand=False), errors='coerce')
```

or if you want to ensure valid floats as independent words:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].astype(str).str.extract('\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b)', 
                           expand=False), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: have you tested this approach? It extracts the first number even if there is a prefix